Pragmatic and objective guide books on vipassana meditation?
Similar to "The Mind Illuminated" and "Core Teachings of the Buddha". Are there any books that offer a pragmatic and objective guide on vipassana meditation, rather than a "spiritual" one?

William Hart's "The Art of Living". There are certain other books published by Vipassana Research Organization which you may find tending to pragmatic aspect. https://www.vridhamma.org/products

Thank you a lot

If it denies rebirth or the importance of unwavering adherence to the precepts it's not pragmatic in any way from the Buddha's perspective.
https://www.dhammatalks.org/suttas/MN/MN60.html
So this one: With Each & Every Breath A Guide To Meditation
Thanissaro Bhikkhu

Vipassana is not related to "rebirth". I marked this answer down. MN 60 is a sutta for puthujjana householders and not related to vipassana.  MN 117 says the views in MN 60 are related to self (acquisitions & asava). Vipassana is related to not-self & ending asava. MN 60 & rebirth are not about vipassana. Vipassana is about impermanence. Impermanence is dissolution  and not rebirth.

My answer doesn't say "vipassanā is related to rebirth." It says that any teaching that denies rebirth is from the Buddha's perspective not "pragmatic." Further, the Buddha's own impetus for gaining liberating insight was to ensure he didn't have to get born again. His teaching on vipassanā only makes sense within the context of rebirth - its purpose is to end birth, hence that being the crucial insight gained at arahantship - see Dhammacakkappavattanasutta and Anattālakkhaṇasutta to name but two. "He knows that 'birth is ended...'"
